# How can I load Angular CLI Build Scripts (Non-AMD) using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, requirejs, angular-datatables

When I build my Angular CLI app I get a list of JavaScript files:

```
- canvg.js
- es2015-polyfills.js
- index.html
- main.js
- pdfmake.js
- polyfills.js
- runtime.js
- scripts.js
- styles.js
- vendor.js
- xlsx.js
```

When I plug these into script tags into a website so that the Angular app is wrapped in a website it loads the Angular app fine except our [Angular Datables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) is broken:

```
$(...).DataTable is not a function
```

I suspect jQuery is not loading before the Angular scripts. (jQuery is loaded by RequireJS from the wrapper site).
I think my solution is to load these Angular build scripts using RequireJs, but they are not AMD. I've looked at shim like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    return {
        init: function(){
            require.config({
                paths:{
                    'runtime': '/app/runtime'
                },
                shim:{
                    'runtime': { deps: ["jquery"] }
                }
            });
            require(['jquery','runtime'], function($){});
        }
    };
});
```

I keep getting something like:

```
Uncaught Error: No define call for runtime
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine
    at makeError (require.min.js:1)
    at Object.completeLoad (require.min.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.min.js:1)
```

I've just been testing with runtime, but ideally I would load all the scripts with RequireJS, and manage those that have a dependency for jQuery as $.

How can I load these angular scripts using RequireJS?